# create model form from model and make one of the attributes hidden

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
class Label(models.Model):
   name = ...
   slug_name = ...
```

and here is the form I created straightly from model

```
class LabelForm(models.Model):
   class Meta:
       model = Label
```

How can I give url the widget `HiddenInput`? `slug_name` also cannot be blank because it is required...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the required field, use [the `blank` field option with a `TextField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank):

```
slug_name = TextField(blank=False)
```

For the `HiddenInput` widget, I assume there exists a url field in your model (which is not the case in the code you posted) check [Django's own guide to overriding the default field types or widgets on a `ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets):

```
class LabelForm(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = Label
        widgets = {'url': HiddenInput()}
```